# asp.net mvc model binder does not work for drop down list in edit mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, modelbinder

why model binder does not work on drop down list in edit mode ?

in edit view i write this code and test two different ddl :

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProductParentCategoryId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductParentCategoryId, (SelectList)ViewBag.ParentId)
```

and in my controller

```
ViewBag.ProductParentCategoryId = new SelectList(_productCategoryService.GetAllProductCategory(), "ProductCategoryId", "ProductCategoryTitle");
ViewBag.ParentId = new SelectList(_productCategoryService.GetAllProductCategory(), "ProductCategoryId", "ProductCategoryTitle");
```

but all textbox in edit mode fill with model binder but not happening for drop down list.

why ?
 [image]

-------UpDate-------

I mean is in edit mode, model binder bind all data from database in textbox and each elements ... 
but in dropdownlist model binder does not bind data from database as **Selected Value** into dropdownlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find my solution 
The only thing that should be done in my controller:

```
[http Get]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var selectedId = _productCategoryService.GetOneProductCategory(id);

        ViewBag.ProductParentCategoryId = new SelectList(_productCategoryService.GetAllProductCategory(), "ProductCategoryId", "ProductCategoryTitle", (int)selectedId.ProductParentCategoryId);
        ViewBag.GroupFiltersId = new SelectList(_groupFiltersService.GetAllGroupFilter().Where(a => a.GroupFilterParentId == null), "GroupFilterId", "GroupFilterTitle");
        return View(_productCategoryService.GetOneProductCategory(id));
    }
```

view:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ProductParentCategoryId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you bind to a view model and not use a ViewBag.

But to answer your question, in your first example you didn't pass the items to populate the dropdown (second parameter) you passed a null value instead.

Also for dropdowns I have always used 
`IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` as opposed to a SelectList collection.

So in your view model you can create a property like: `public IEnumerable<ProductCategory> ProductCategories {get; set;}` and bind it to your dropdown as follows:

```
Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProductCategoryId, Model.ProductCategories)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg548304(v=vs.111).aspx